# Datastax C# drops connection to Cassandra cluster in EC2

Tags: c#, amazon-ec2, cassandra, datastax

I've got problem with Datastax C# driver (...or Amazon EC2). My Laptop is connected to test Cassandra Cluster (1 node in EC2). This issue occurs only when connecting from my laptop to Amazon EC2. After deployment to EC2, there are no problems between application in EC2 and Cassandra in EC2.

### Step 1.

My application is not using Cassandra - I've set therefore `poolingOptions.SetHeartBeatInterval(6666)` to keep connection alive. This seems to work:

```
Cassandra.Connection: 09-02-2015 11:37:49.270 +02:00 Read #0 for Opcode 8 from host CassandraNodeIP:9042 
Cassandra.Connection: 09-02-2015 11:37:51.020 +02:00 Connection idling, issuing a Request to prevent idle
Cassandra.Connection: 09-02-2015 11:37:51.020 +02:00 Sending #0 for QueryRequest 
Cassandra.Connection: 09-02-2015 11:37:51.093 +02:00 Read #0 for Opcode 8 from host CassandraNodeIP:9042 
Cassandra.Connection: 09-02-2015 11:37:55.350 +02:00 Connection idling, issuing a Request to prevent idle
Cassandra.Connection: 09-02-2015 11:37:55.351 +02:00 Sending #0 for QueryRequest 
Cassandra.Connection: 09-02-2015 11:37:55.424 +02:00 Read #0 for Opcode 8 from host CassandraNodeIP:9042 
Cassandra.Connection: 09-02-2015 11:37:55.865 +02:00 Connection idling, issuing a Request to prevent idle
Cassandra.Connection: 09-02-2015 11:37:55.865 +02:00 Sending #0 for QueryRequest 
Cassandra.Connection: 09-02-2015 11:37:55.938 +02:00 Read #0 for Opcode 8 from host CassandraNodeIP:9042 
Cassandra.Connection: 09-02-2015 11:37:57.700 +02:00 Connection idling, issuing a Request to prevent idle
Cassandra.Connection: 09-02-2015 11:37:57.700 +02:00 Sending #0 for QueryRequest
```

and much more of these.

### Step 2.

After a while (e.g. 3min) I want to insert data to Cassandra, however this happens and **only part of data** is inserted:

```
Cassandra.NoHostAvailableException: None of the hosts tried for query are available (tried: )
    in Cassandra.RequestHandler`1.GetNextConnection(IStatement statement)
    in csharp-driver\src\Cassandra\RequestHandler.cs:line 182
    in Cassandra.RequestHandler`1.TrySend()
```

and much more of these.

Questions:

- is it Datastax C# driver bug/misconfiguration or Amazon EC2 'alive time' connections limit?
- how to fix it?

### EDIT:

I've tried exactly that scenario one day later - there were no issues. Therefore here is full log from yesterday - maybe someone will figure out what happened...

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/91a8edeab215a31b3d5f

Comment: You should have in the driver trace the reason why all your nodes are considered as down by the driver. Trace level info should be enough to see it.

Comment: Sorry to take your time @jorgebg, as today I tried it again - it works fine... However I've pasted whole log from yesterday - it will be probably easier for you to scroll and skim for what you need to see. Maybe you will be able to tell what's the reason for all of this.